# The set of all real functions of a real variable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How can I prove that the set of all real functions of a real variable,
>   or even that the set of functions that take only the values 0 and 1,
>   more than the continuum?

---

I have one idea, but it's not remarkable for its rigor and formality. I suppose that the power of all real functions is $\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c}$ and the power of all functions that take only the values 0 and 1 -- $2^\mathfrak{c}$. So how $$\mathfrak{c}^\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_{0}\mathfrak{c}}=2^\mathfrak{c}>\mathfrak{c}.$$
Could you give more rigorous proof?

Comment: If you can argue that $\mathfrak{c}^{\mathfrak{c}}\ge2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ then that's enough. I'm not certain where the "$2^{\aleph_0 \mathfrak{c}}$" is coming from.

Comment: The same argument that shows that $2^{\mathbb N} > \mathbb N$ should apply here. Assume by way of contradiction that there is a bijection $f:\mathbb R\to 2^{\mathbb R}$ and consider the subset $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ defined by $r\in S$ if and only if $r \notin f(r)$. Then $S$ is not in the image of $f$.

Comment: @JohnBrevik In other words, to apply to my last words of Cantor's theorem?

Comment: Yes, if I understand what you mean by that!

Comment: Wait, your last words are Cantor's theorem? That is epic. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S=\{f:\Bbb R\to\{0,1\}\}$ and let $\alpha:\Bbb R\to S$ be surjective. Define for each $x\in\Bbb R$
$$f(x)=1-\alpha(x)(x)$$

Note that $f\in S$. Since $\alpha$ is surjective, there exists some $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha(y)=f$. Then
$$f(y)=1-\alpha(y)(y)=1-f(y)$$
which is a contradiction.

*Remark*: Note that $\Bbb R$, or even its cardinality, doesn't play any special role in the proof, so it could have been any nonempty set. Thus,

> If $X$ is a nonempty set, the cardinal of $2^X$ is strictly greater than the cardinal of $X$.

The statement is also true for $X=\emptyset$, since $2^0>0$.

Comment: Thanks! And how to prove the Cantor's theorem I know, so now I haven't any problems!

Comment: @AbrahamDaniel: ajotatxe's proof _is_ the standard diagonalization  proof of Cantor's theorem written in a functional way.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be some set.  Then $|2^S| > |S|$, where $2^S$ denotes the power set of $S$, and the set of functions from $S$ to ${0,1}$ has an obvious bijection with the power set of $S$.

Basically it is a one-step reduction to cantor's theorem -- the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is equal in size to the power set of $\mathbb{R}$.

$|2^S| > |S|$ is Cantor's theorem.  For empty $S$ check it manually.  For non-empty $S$:

Clearly $|2^S|\geq |S|$<sup>footnote 1</sup>.  So assume there is an surjection $f:S\to2^S$.

Define $Q_f := \{ x \in S : x \notin f(x)\}$, the Cantor diagonal set of $f$.

By surjectivity, $\exists y \in A : f(y) = Q_f$ (here is where I use non-empty).

Either $y \in Q_f$ or $y \notin Q_f$.

If $y \in Q_f$, then by construction of $Q_f$, $y \notin Q_f$.

If $y \notin Q_f$, then $y \notin f(y)$, and by definition of $Q_f$ we have $y \in Q_f$.

Only one assumption was made, and we have a contradiction, so there is no surjection from $S \to 2^S$.  Which means $2^S > S$.

---

<sup>1</sup> $\{\{x\}\}$ is in $2^S$ for each $x \in S$